# Set variable name with string variable in VBA

Tags: excel, declare, vba

I have to create many variables inside a loop, so I need to create generic variable names (note, for the purpose of my code, i can't just append the objects i want to create to a list or collection)

The code I was thinking looks something like this (n is a user defined variable, and its an integer)

```
Dim var_name As String

For i = 1 To n
    var_name = "test" & i
    Set var_name = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i * 2, i))
Next i
```

I would like to obtain variables like this:

- test1 being a range from A1 to B2
- test2 being a range from A1 to C4
- test3 being a range from A1 to D6
- .... testn being a range from A1 to whatever

They dont necesarily have to be range, **all I really want is to declare a variable name using a string stored in another variable**

Comment: What you're asking cannot be done in VBA although it can be doe in [tag:asp-classic] and I think [tag:vbscript]. You need to work with arrays or possibly named ranges.

Comment: btw, your loop creates A1:A2, A1:B4, A1:C6, etc.

Comment: Have a look at `Scripting.Dictionary`. The syntax would be a little more verbose, but (based on your example) it should be able to give you very similar functionality.

Comment: Use an array of type Range, dimensioned from 1 to n.  You can't have variable variable names in VBA, and since it seems `i`is the real key here, you can just use that directly against an array.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an array?

```
Dim Test()
ReDim Test(0)
...
```

As you receive new data, just ReDim Preserve your array:

```
ReDim Preserve Test(UBound(Test)+1)
Test(UBound(Test)) = <new data>
```

I find it easiest to leave the array's variable type as the default Variant, but that is personal preference and how you use the variable.  For example if you send it to other Functions or Sub xxx(Tst() *as String*) then you would have to send it as xxx(*CStr*(Test(i))),  which is less convenient.