# Creating a Collection as the Value of a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to create a Dictionary that contains a collection as its value because I have multiple variables, which have different amounts of properties. I was hoping to avoid creating a class.

```
Sub test()

    Set dict = CreateDict()

    Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub

Private Function CreateDict() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare


    Set wb = CreateObject("excel.Application").Workbooks.Open("S:\filename.xlsx")
    Set wks = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Row = 2
    Do While IsEmpty(wks.Cells(Row, 1)) = False

        key = wks.Cells(Row, 1)
        value = wks.Cells(Row, 3)

        'Debug.Print key, value

        If dict.Exists(key) Then
            dict(key).Add value
        Else
            Dim col As New Collection
            col.Add value
            dict.Add key, col
        End If

        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

    Workbooks("filename.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

    Dim key1 As Variant
    For Each key1 In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key1, dict(key1)(1)
    Next key1

    Set CreateDict = dict
End Function
```

My keys are added correctly but when I try and access the first value of my collection it is empty, even though if I print `value` before it is not empty.

I hope I did not do a stupid mistake I just started with VBA a week ago. Any help would be appreciated, also if there is an easier way to do it or if there is an existing way to do this I would be glad to find out.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

For anyone wondering unfortunately this does not work as stated above, because VBA does not create a new Collection everytime `Dim col As New Collection` is applied. Instead all values are just added to one Collection `col`. However I found a workaround, since dynamic variable names are not possible in VBA, according to this post [Set variable name with string variable in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614408/set-variable-name-with-string-variable-in-vba).

However I just created a function which creates and returns a collection. My code looks now as following:

```
Sub test()

    Set dict = CreateDict()

    Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub

Private Function CreateDict() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare


    Set wb = CreateObject("excel.Application").Workbooks.Open("S:\filename.xlsx")
    Set wks = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Row = 2
    Do While IsEmpty(wks.Cells(Row, 1)) = False

        key = wks.Cells(Row, 1)
        value = wks.Cells(Row, 3)

        'Debug.Print key, value

        If dict.Exists(key) Then
            dict(key).Add value
        Else
            dict.Add key, CreateCollection()
            dict(key).Add value
        End If

        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

    Workbooks("filename.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

    Set CreateDict = dict
End Function

Private Function CreateCollection() As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection
    Set CreateCollection = col
End Function
```

Comment: For what it's worth, instead of `CreateCollection()`, you should be able to do `dict.Add key, New Collection`.  The sequence `Dim col as Collection: Set col = New Collection` is another way to create a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `dict(key1)(0)`, expand the code as follows:

```
Dim c as Collection
Set c = dict(key1)
Debug.Print c(1)    ' or c.item(1)
```

Two issues:

- Collections are indexed starting at 1<sup>†</sup>
- VBA sometimes fails to properly resolve chained method calls if it doesn't have type information.

<sup>†</sup> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-method-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tested it, but unfortunately I still get the same result

Comment: Ahh actually it worked, I at first only changed the indexing mentioned by you which did not work. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Nils Glad to hear it!  I edited the answer to reflect your comments.